# It is valid that $A \subset B$. Prove that $A \cap B = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

We did this example on the lectures, but I don't understand how did the proffesor got solution, so I was hoping that somebody can tell me how did he got the solution. Thanks.

This is what he wrote on the blackboard:

$$
A \subset B \implies A \cap A \subset B \cap A\\
A \subset B \implies A \subset B \cap A\\
B \cap A \subset A\\
$$

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you know that $A \cap A = A$?

Comment: Try some examples.

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He starts with the given inclusion, $A\subseteq B$. Then he intersects both sides with the set $A$ and uses the fact that if $X\subset Y$, then $X\cap Z\subseteq Y\cap Z$ no matter what set $Z$ is; this gives him the inclusion $A\cap A\subseteq B\cap A$. Then he uses the fact that $X\cap X=X$ no matter what set $X$ is to say that $A\cap A=A$; this reduces the inclusion $A\cap A\subseteq B\cap A$ to $A\subseteq B\cap A$.

The last step is separate from the others. It’s another general fact that $X\cap Y\subseteq Y$ no matter what the sets $X$ and $Y$ are, so $B\cap A\subseteq A$.

Now he puts the results together: it’s another general fact that if $X\subseteq Y$ and $Y\subseteq X$, then $X=Y$. We have $A\subseteq B\cap A$ and $B\cap A\subseteq A$, so we can conclude that $A\cap B=A$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $A\subseteq B$.

$\textbf{Claim 1:}\quad$ $A\cap B\subseteq A$.

$\textit{Proof:}\quad$ Suppose that $x\in A\cap B$. Then, $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. In particular, $x\in A$. Therefore, $x\in A\cap B$ implies that $x\in A$. Therefore, $A\cap B\subseteq A$. $\blacksquare$

$\textbf{Claim 2:}\quad$ $A\subseteq A\cap B$

$\textit{Proof:}\quad$ Suppose that $x\in A$. Then, since $A\subseteq B$, $x\in B$, too. Therefore, $x\in A$ and $x\in B$, so that $x\in A\cap B$. Hence, $x\in A$ implies that $x\in A\cap B$, so that $A\subseteq A\cap B$. $\blacksquare$

Put the two claims together to conclude that $A=A\cap B$.